# How can I prepend a random letter/number to the beginning of each filename?

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts, filename

I'm working on a system where I'd like the first letter of each filename to be random - not necessarily *unique*, just random. I'd like to be able to run this from a cron job.

For example, I would be able to point it at a list of files like

```
song.mp3    song1.mp3    song2.mp3
song3.mp3   song4.mp3    song5.mp3
```

And have it change the names of the files to something like this:

```
a song.mp3    g song1.mp3    k song2.mp3
r song3.mp3   l song4.mp3    e song5.mp3
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? [There may be a better way to accomplish your underlying goal](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) depending on what it is (possibly involving `shuf` and process substitution).

Comment: I'm using mpg123 to play .mp3 files, and I'd like for them to be randomized *and loop* - so I'm needing to randomize the names. If you have any better ideas to accomplish this, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: [According to the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpg123), mpg123 has a `--random` option, which will play the songs randomly and never stop. Alternatively, it *looks* like you could use a combination of `--shuffle` and `--loop 0` to get what you want (I think these will each give you different behaviour: `--random` will select a random file every time; `--shuffle`/`--loop 0` will create a random list once, at the beginning, and then loop through that list infinitely. Unless I'm misinterpreting the `--loop` option. You'll have to test it yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this script. I tried the exactly what you wanted.

```
#!/bin/bash

for item in *.mp3
do
    mv "$item" "$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-z' | head -c 1) $item"
done
```

**How does random letters picked up**

Here I am picking up strings from `/dev/urandom` and deleting all the characters which are not in between [a-z] and at last keeping only the first letter.

**How to use**

Copy the code to a file, say `rename_song.sh`, give it execution permission using terminal as follows,

```
chmod +x /path/to/rename_song.sh
```

Copy `rename_song.sh` to the directory where you have `.mp3` files. run the script from terminal (first navigate to the directory where you have `.mp3` files) as,

```
./rename_song.sh
```

If you have a list of files like

```
song.mp3    song1.mp3    song2.mp3
song3.mp3   song4.mp3    song5.mp3
```

They will be renamed like this:

```
a song.mp3    g song1.mp3    k song2.mp3
r song3.mp3   P song4.mp3    A song5.mp3
```

If you want letter as well as number then replace `tr -cd 'a-z'` by `tr -cd 'a-z0-9'`, and it is always better to use a simple shell glob instead of parsing the output of `ls`.

Comment: Yes, the shell glob * is much better. I'll change mine.

Comment: I have the script in the directory containing all the files, but running the script (as root) gives me a `mv: target 'bla.mp3' is not a directory` for each mp3. Any ideas?

Comment: @Undo I made a small change, but I think it was not the problem. Now follow the instruction and try. And unless the `.mp3` files are in special location (not accessible to normal user) you never should run it as root.

Comment: let me know if the script is working or not?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the env variable $RANDOM:

```
#!/bin/bash
for F in *.mp3 ; do
    mv $F $RANDOM.$F
done
```

Which will move files:

```
songa.mp3
song7.mp3
```

to

```
1875.songa.mp3
32654.song7.mp3
```

for example.

Comment: Nice script - may I mention that this needs to be done from the same directory, in an executable text file - unless of course it is done as a one-liner in terminal...

Comment: There's no need to use `ls`, you might as well just `for F in *.mp3; do mv -- "$F" "$RANDOM.$F" ; done` (it's also good to quote your variables, so that it doesn't break on filenames containing spaces, and the `--` after the `mv` ensures that it won't break on any filenames starting with a `-`).

Comment: As long as it works, it should be fine - arguing over script is for StackOverflow @evilsoup. Anyway, I'll update my one-liner carbon copy :-)

Comment: Haha! At least nobody has told the OP he doesn't really want to given them names like that.

Comment: @wilf I hope it didn't come across as argumentative, it wasn't meant to. I do think it's important to spread good scripting practices like quoting variables, though.

Comment: Didn't come across that way at all to me. Indeed good pointing out the shortcomings. I originally ditched the quotes because my browser was doing some smart-quote weirdnesses.

Comment: It is a good idea - I utterly forgot about the commenting variables :-) - I tested it on a folder full of copied mp3's, but all the songs have dashes between the words...

Answer (score 1):

Here are the one-liner versions of @Joseph's script so you can paste it into terminal:

First change to the desired directory:

`cd /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/`

and then you can run the command directly from terminal:

```
for F in $(ls *.mp3); do mv "$F" "$RANDOM.$F" ;  done;
```

and a shorter version of it would be:

```
for F in *.mp3 ; do mv "$F" "$RANDOM.$F" ; done
```

May I also note that these will only do random numbers at the beginning anyway.